# Does the Thundering Herd Problem exist on Linux anymore?

Tags: linux, scalability

Many linux/unix programming books and tutorials speak about the ["Thundering Herd Problem"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thundering_herd_problem) which happens when multiple threads or forks are blocked on a select() call waiting for readability of a listening socket. When the connection comes in, all threads and forks are woken up but only one "wins" with a successful call to "accept()". In the meantime, a lot of cpu time is wasted waking up all the threads/forks for no reason.

I noticed a [project](http://www.citi.umich.edu/projects/linux-scalability/reports/accept.html) which provides a "fix" for this problem in the linux kernel, but this is a very old patch.

I think there are two variants; One where each fork does select() and then accept(), and one that just does accept().

Do modern unix/linux kernels still have the Thundering Herd Problem in both these cases or only the "select() then accept()" version?

Comment: never heard of this, but a lot of stuff the "linux kernel does badly", definitely isn't true any longer!

Comment: That's a very interesting question.  It would be really hard to handle well in the `select` then `accept` case because you can't guarantee that the process that is doing `select` will eventually `accept`.  I think someone should run a test to find out, and maybe test `epoll` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's there and it's real. See this issue that we are seeing in uwsgi: https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/issues/2611

If I disable the --thunder-lock option in uwsgi, that means uwsgi won't be using right api/locking mechanism of system. In that case during my peak load I could see lot of context switch and lot of time wasted. Consistent high response time of my application. (I am talking 1 Lac request per min on my server) at this moment.

Answer (score 17):

For years, most unix/linux kernels serialize response to accept(2)s, in other words, only one thread is waken up if more than one are blocking on accept(2) against a single open file descriptor.

OTOH, many (if not all) kernels still have the thundering herd problem in the select-accept pattern as you describe.

I have written a simple script ( https://gist.github.com/kazuho/10436253 ) to verify the existence of the problem, and found out that the problem exists on linux 2.6.32 and Darwin 12.5.0 (OS X 10.8.5).

Comment: Thank you for the succinct test! For reference, I just tried running it in select-accept mode on linux 3.2.0-58:$ perl thundering-herd.pl select-accept
connected! at thundering-herd.pl line 49.
accept failed:Resource temporarily unavailable at thundering-herd.pl line 52. - And in 'accept' mode, there is no thunder.

Comment: This tells me that the thundering herd problem does still exist and this means that one should either have all threads doing accept() without select() or have one thread doing select() and then accept() and then pass the fd to a worker thread for processing.

Comment: This problem also exists on my ubuntu 8.04 (linux 2.6.24)

Comment: If you use epoll instead of select you can avoid this problem, with the EPOLLEXCLUSIVE flag

Answer (score 12):

This is a very old problem, and for the most part does not exist any more. The Linux kernel (for the past few years) has had a number of changes with the way it handles and routes packets up the network stack, and includes many optimizations to ensure both low latency, and fairness (i.e., minimize starvation).

That said, the *select* system has a number of scalability issues simply by way of its API. When you have a large number of file descriptors, the cost of a select call is very high. This is primarily due to having to build, check, and maintain the FD sets that are passed to and from the system call.

Now days, the preferred way to do asynchronous IO is with *epoll*. The API is far simpler and scales very nicely across various types of load (many connections, lots of throughput, etc.)

Comment: I'm thinking of the situation where there is only one socket per fork and the socket is blocking. So epoll() vs poll() vs select() doesn't matter here.  Does linux have special task waking behaviour for listening sockets now?

Comment: Yes, IIRC, the implementation now wakes up only one thread (as opposed to waking up all threads and having them compete.)

How it picks the thread is complicated, but the simple answer is: it's priority based, so it relies on the scheduler to maintain fairness.

Anyhow, that specific herding problem does not exist anymore so the situation isn't as dire upon overload.

All this said, using select instead of epoll does incur a higher CPU cost (both in the kernel and in user-space), which is, IMO, negligible for your use-case.

Answer (score 2):

I recently saw tested a scenario where multiple threads polled on a listening unix-domain socket and then accepted the connection. All threads woke up using the poll() system call.

This was a custom build of the linux kernel rather than a distro build so perhaps there is a kernel configure option that changes it but I don't know what that would be.

We did not try epoll.

Answer (score 2):

Refer the link below which talks about separate flags to epoll to avoid this problem.

http://lwn.net/Articles/632590/

Comment: And also http://lwn.net/Articles/633422/ which talks about new EPOLLEXCLUSIVE flag to be added...