# Calling accept() from multiple threads

Tags: linux, multithreading, concurrency, tcp

I'm writing a concurrent TCP server that has to handle multiple connections with the **'thread per connection'** approach (using a **thread pool**). My doubt is about which is the most optimal way for every thread to get a different file descriptor.

I found that the next two methods are the most recommended:

1. A **main thread** that `accepts()` all the incoming connections and **stores** their descriptors on a data structure (e.g.: a `queue`). Then every thread is able to get an fd from the queue.
2. Accept() is **called directly from every thread**. (Recommended in [Unix Network Programming V1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131411551) )

---

Problems I find to each of them:

1. The static data structure that stores all the fd's must be **locked** (`mutex_lock`) before a thread can read from it, so in the case that a considerable number of threads wants to read in **exactly the same moment** I don't know how much time would pass until all of them would get their goal.
2. I've been reading that the [Thundering Herd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thundering_herd_problem) problem related to simultaneous `accept()` calls has not been totally solved on Linux yet, so maybe I would need to create an **artificial solution** to it that would end up making the application at least as slow as with the approach 1.

---

**Sources:**

(Some links talking about approach 2: [does-the-thundering-herd-problem-exist-on-linux-anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213779/does-the-thundering-herd-problem-exist-on-linux-anymore) - and one article I found about it (outdated) : [linux-scalability/reports/accept.html](http://www.citi.umich.edu/projects/linux-scalability/reports/accept.html)

And an SO answer that recommends approach 1: [can-i-call-accept-for-one-socket-from-several-threads-simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488453/can-i-call-accept-for-one-socket-from-several-threads-simultaneously)

---

I'm really interested on the matter, so I will appreciate any opinion about it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488453/can-i-call-accept-for-one-socket-from-several-threads-simultaneously) you linked, a single thread calling accept() is probably the way to go.  You mention concerns about locking, but these days you will find lockfree queue implementations available in [Boost.Lockfree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost/lockfree/queue.html), [Intel TBB](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/containers_overview/concurrent_queue_cls.htm), and elsewhere.  You could use one of those if you like, but you might just use a condition variable to let your worker threads sleep and wake one of them when a new connection is established.

Comment: Thanks for the idea of the condition variable, I think that it can make the approach quite efficient. Anyway I would like to know if the second approach may be feasible or not (only to dispel some of my doubts). (p.s.: By the moment i will not accept your answer because I'd like to get other people's opinions :))

Comment: The second approach should be de rigueur for any queue implementation you write for this scenario anyway.  If you don't use a condvar internal to the queue the thread clients are reduced to constantly polling to see if there is data when what you really want is for them to sleep until there something to do i.e. block when there is nothing in the queue to read.