# When multiple processes listen to the same port, how OS loads balance traffic between them?

Tags: linux, sockets, network-programming

According to [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694144/can-two-applications-listen-to-the-same-port), multiple processes could listen to the same IP and same port. This is good.

In my case, we are super CPU-bound. So I want to know in this case, how OS load balance incoming traffic to multiple processes. Can it be balanced well since OS knows everything? Or it just blindly round robin?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does the Thundering Herd Problem exist on Linux anymore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213779/does-the-thundering-herd-problem-exist-on-linux-anymore)

Comment: If you're referring to TCP, you can't. If you're referring to UDP, all processes get all datagrams. There is no load balancing.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne: Doesn't [this article](https://lwn.net/Articles/542629/) say otherwise?